# PHP to SQLSERVER database connection procedure

Tags: php, windows, sql-server-2008, iis

I have done each and everything regarding configuration of PHP with Windows Server/Windows 8

Even simple echo string is running but connection with SQL database is not working....

I have searched the whole internet for this.

As i am new to windows server please help me out to make PHP run on windows and get data from SQL database.

Please give me step by step procedure so i will know where i am lacking?

Thank you!

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this :

```
 <?php
    $serverName = "serverName\sqlexpress"; //serverName\instanceName
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbName", "UID"=>"userName", "PWD"=>"password");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

    if( $conn ) {
         echo "ok.<br />";
    }else{
         echo "crashed.<br />";
         die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
    ?>
```

But you need to do research on Internet there are a lot of examples of connections between php and SQL Server :

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.sqlsrv-connect.php

Edit :

You can also try this :

```
$myServer = "10.85.80.229";
$myUser = "root";
$myPass = "pass";
$myDB = "testdb";

$conn = mssql_connect($myServer,$myUser,$myPass);
if (!$conn)
{ 
  die('Not connected : ' . mssql_get_last_message());
} 
$db_selected = mssql_select_db($myDB, $conn);
if (!$db_selected) 
{
  die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mssql_get_last_message());
}
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mssql.installation.php

Comment: Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. 
This error is thrown! :(

Comment: Just reed the error message . You cannot access to your server cause he is not found or accessible . If you're sure that the server is working that mean that your informations in the code are wrong . Check the instance name, password , connections .
The code is obviously right you need to do research on what the error tell you . I edit my answer with an other way to do it , try it

Comment: Did you achieve your work ?

Comment: yes absolutely, my server credentials were wrong. thank you

Comment: Now just, put that your problem is "resolved" by checking my answer , for other people please .